# isWallsupportSupported() returns false

Tags: android, android-studio, android-automotive

Does anyone have any information on why running `isWallpaperSupported()` returns `false` on Android Automotive OS? Is there any way to change it? Is there no way to set wallpapers currently in Automotive OS?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Supported app categories](https://developer.android.com/training/cars#supported-app-categories), only media, messaging, and "navigation, parking, and charging" apps are supported on Automotive OS.

There is no wallpaper functionality on Automotive OS, nor any type of app that would supported that would allow you to change the wallpaper.